# Change Node-RED UI button color via MQTT

Tags: mqtt, node-red

I have a node-red flow on a raspberry pi home security network, using MQTT as a message bus. How would one change colors on the UI buttons based on incoming MQTT messages?

I've not been able to find any examples of how to do this anywhere. I imagine this will be tied to CSS and javascript but I'm weak in these areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to do this is described in the info tab for the dashboard ui button:

> The colours of the text and background may be set. They can also be set by a message property by setting the field to the name of the property, for example {{msg.background}}.

so you can set the background of the button by configuring the button like this:

[image]

Then passing in a message with the `msg.backgound` set to the colour you want (colours can be any CSS colour safe name).

You can use a function node or a change node to add the `background` property to the msg before passing it to the ui-button node.

Comment: Perfect; thanks.  This is not in the info tab for my version! I must have an older version of node-red; it's been about a year since I installed it.

Comment: Implementing this fix, I see where if I send a msg to a button, it triggers the button as though it were clicked on the UI. Can I prevent this? I use the button to send a command to MQTT, and a different MQTT payload should set the button color.

Comment: until the "pass message through" check box in the config

Comment: I only see that option on ui_switch, not on ui_button

Comment: Then make sure you upgrade to the latest version. ( check box is labeled as `If msg arrives on input, pass through to output` )

Comment: I did an upgrade earlier today with "sudo npm cache clean", then 
 " sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-red", then rebooted the Pi... did I miss something?

Comment: The dashboard is separate to node-red. The dashboard is `node-red-dashboard`